# django ORM join statements

Tags: django

I'm learning django queryset API and it's so overwhelming. I'm used to sql statement and I just want a basic join statement where 2 tables join together

How can i get this result in shell?

```
SELECT e.emp_lastname,e.emp_firstname,o.job_description
FROM hs_hr_employee e
INNER JOIN ohrm_job_title o ON e.job_title_code = o.id
WHERE e.work_station='101';
```

hs_hr_employee

```
from django.db import models

class HsHrEmployee(models.Model):
emp_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
emp_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
emp_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
job_title_code = models.ForeignKey('OhrmJobTitle', models.DO_NOTHING, 
db_column='job_title_code', blank=True, null=True)
work_station = models.ForeignKey('OhrmSubunit', models.DO_NOTHING, 
db_column='work_station', blank=True, null=True)
```

hs_hr_job_title

```
class OhrmJobTitle(models.Model):
job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
job_description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, 
null=True)
```

i added the models

Comment: Please provide your django models that we can get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
qs = HsHrEmployee.objects.filter(
    work_station_id=101
).select_related('job_title_code')
```

For the `HsHrEmployee` model objects that arise from this queryset, you can then determine the `job_title` for example with:

```
for item in qs:
    print(item.job_title_code.job_title)
```

Comment: this code prints only the positions. I want something like lastname,position. something like item.emp_lastname.job_title but its not showing output

Comment: i can do like item.emp_lastname but how can i add the job_description

Comment: i got it {{ list.emp_lastname }} {{ list.job_title_code.job_title }} its generic views complelty forgot